# How predict more than one image in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I Am trying to run a project from [github](https://github.com/rohanbaisantry/image-clustering) , I am trying to cluster images, but when I run the project I get an error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (500, 150528)`
I tried to debug the project and I found that it caused by those two functions

```
def load_images(self):
    self.images = []
    for image in self.image_paths:
        self.images.append(
            cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(self.folder_path + "\\" + image), (224, 224)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    self.images = np.float32(self.images).reshape(len(self.images), -1)
    self.images /= 255
    print("\n " + str(
        self.max_examples) + " images from the \"" + self.folder_path + "\" folder have been loaded in a random order.")
```

and

```
pred = VGG16.predict(self.images)
```

I am not quite sure if am using it correctly or the project need some modifications
but how can I adapt the code to predict the images in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In like [50](https://github.com/rohanbaisantry/image-clustering/blob/master/image_clustering.py#L50) you have mentioned that `VGG16` accepts inputs of shape `(224,224,3)` but when you load the [image](https://github.com/rohanbaisantry/image-clustering/blob/master/image_clustering.py#L41) you reshape it into `(500,150528)` that's why you get an error. Change line [41](https://github.com/rohanbaisantry/image-clustering/blob/master/image_clustering.py#L41) into

```
self.images = np.float32(self.images).reshape(len(self.images), 224,224,3)
```